# Recovering deleted transaction data from SQL Server database and log in Simple Recovery Model

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

We have a SQL Server 2005 database whose reovery model is **Simple**. One of the users has deleted few important records from few tables accidentally. It is not possible to recover the data from SQL Server transaction logs when the recovery modle is Simple. I have heard that there are recovery tools like EnCase, Evidence Eliminator etc., using which one can recover the deleted files from the hard disk. Can it be possible to restore the state of disk files at any point in time? Please provide your inputs.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx with simple recovery model there are no log backups, you should restore from a previous backup